# I am trying to create Matrix Effect, but i get some error at form load (Invalid window handle)

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Console.Title = "Matrix Effect"
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen
        Console.WindowLeft = InlineAssignHelper(0, 0)
        Console.WindowHeight = InlineAssignHelper(Console.BufferHeight, Console.LargestWindowHeight)
        Console.WindowWidth = InlineAssignHelper(Console.BufferWidth, Console.LargestWindowWidth)

        Console.CursorVisible = False
        Dim width As Integer, height As Integer
        Dim y As Integer()
        Dim l As Integer()
        Initialize(width, height, y, l)
        Dim ms As Integer
        While True
            Dim t1 As DateTime = DateTime.Now
            MatrixStep(width, height, y, l)
            ms = 10 - CInt(Math.Truncate(CType(DateTime.Now - t1, TimeSpan).TotalMilliseconds))
            If ms > 0 Then
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ms)
            End If
            If Console.KeyAvailable Then
                If Console.ReadKey().Key = ConsoleKey.F5 Then
                    Initialize(width, height, y, l)
                End If
            End If
        End While
    End Sub

    Dim thistime As Boolean = False

    Private Sub MatrixStep(ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer, ByVal y As Integer(), ByVal l As Integer())
        Dim x As Integer
        thistime = Not thistime
        For x = 0 To width - 1
            If x Mod 11 = 10 Then
                If Not thistime Then
                    Continue For
                End If
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Else
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, inBoxY(y(x) - 2 - ((l(x) \ 40) * 2), height))
                Console.Write(R)
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            End If
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y(x))
            Console.Write(R)
            y(x) = inBoxY(y(x) + 1, height)
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, inBoxY(y(x) - l(x), height))
            Console.Write(" "c)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Initialize(ByRef width As Integer, ByRef height As Integer, ByRef y As Integer(), ByRef l As Integer())
        Dim h1 As Integer
        Dim h2 As Integer = (InlineAssignHelper(h1, (InlineAssignHelper(height, Console.WindowHeight)) \ 2)) \ 2
        width = Console.WindowWidth - 1
        y = New Integer(width - 1) {}
        l = New Integer(width - 1) {}
        Dim x As Integer
        Console.Clear()
        For x = 0 To width - 1
            y(x) = m_r.[Next](height)
            l(x) = m_r.[Next](h2 * (If((x Mod 11 <> 10), 2, 1)), h1 * (If((x Mod 11 <> 10), 2, 1)))
        Next
    End Sub

    Dim m_r As New Random()
    Private ReadOnly Property R() As Char
        Get
            Dim t As Integer = m_r.[Next](10)
            If t <= 2 Then
                Return ChrW(CInt(AscW("0"c)) + m_r.[Next](10))
            ElseIf t <= 4 Then
                Return ChrW(CInt(AscW("a"c)) + m_r.[Next](27))
            ElseIf t <= 6 Then
                Return ChrW(CInt(AscW("A"c) + m_r.[Next](27)))
            Else
                Return ChrW(m_r.[Next](32, 255))
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function inBoxY(ByVal n As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Integer
        n = n Mod height
        If n < 0 Then
            Return n + height
        Else
            Return n
        End If
    End Function
    Private Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Might want to move your question into your question and change the title

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894756/i-am-trying-to-create-matrix-effect-but-i-get-some-error-invalid-window-handle). And it still has nothing to do with VBScript or VB6. Please don't do this.

Comment: Sorry, but YOU didn't try anything but copy&paste and then ask someone to make it work. >> http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?645452-Matrix-Effect

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a WinForm to display a Console, that won't work.

replace:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
...
End Class
```

with this:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
...
End Module
```